# The Big D, little a double l-a

Tags: abbreviations

What is the meaning of "little a double l-a"? The phrase comes from "[Big D](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.allmusicals.com/lyrics/mosthappyfellathe/bigd.htm)" lyrics. I know Big D refers to Dallas. I am sorry if I have asked a question that has an obvious answer. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: The guy is so proud of coming from Dallas that he's written a whole song about it, with lyrics that include ***spelling it out***. Same as sports-team supporting  ***cheerleaders***. What exactly is it you don't understand? In this context ***little*** means ***lower-case*** (written letter "a") and ***double-l*** means the letter 'l' occurs twice in a row in the name of the city (you missed out the final ***s*** from the lyrics).

Comment: _Double_ is regularly used that way in spelling out words (and numbers) in British English, but I thought it was little known in the US. In the days before the Internet, I remember ringing International Directory Enquiries, and hearing the English operator spelling a name out to an American operator using "double", which the American misinterpreted as "w".

Comment: @ColinFine We do use *double* some in the US - for example, the National Collegiate Athletic Association is commonly called the ["N C double A"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Collegiate_Athletic_Association#Notes), and [AAMCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAMCO_Transmissions)   had commercials which ended "Aamco, double A (honk honk) M C O" but it isn't terribly common; for example I can't really imagine an American spelling out "Rinnegan" by saying "R I double N..."

Comment: I've noticed that other English speakers don't always know that we (Brits) often say 'oh' for zero, so something like 455006 said as 'four double five double oh six' can cause problems

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  I would have thought that everyone was familiar with that practice, due to the famous British export Double O Seven!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lyrics are spelling out the word "Dallas": "Big *D*", then "little a" is a lowercase *A*, then "double l" is two lowercase *L*s, then *A* *S* spells *Dallas*.

Comment: Thank you all for your detailed explanations!